# C++ zip library with unicode file names support

Tags: c++, unicode, zlib

I have a C++ project, it supports zip (zlib library is used) file processing. Now I've got a task to add support of unicode file names in zip files. So, is there some zlib fork, that supports unicode or maybe I should use another library?

Comment: [Since when zlib reads/writes zip archives?](http://zlib.net/zlib_faq.html#faq11)

Comment: I think you mean gzip since you reference zlib.  I use boost-zlib for this task.

Comment: gzip and zlib are compression programs, and do not deal with Unicode: they compress streams of bytes. The .zip format, a different beast entirely, stores directory structures, and thus, filenames and other text data. Similarly, .tar does as well.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717068/using-zlib-with-unicode-file-paths-on-windows